# Skeletonization in opencv

Tags: opencv

Is there any specific function that can be used in opencv for skeletonization? Besides, i searched for some time and want to know if opencv implements voronoi-skeleton (seems like there is but is it really are)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like Voronoi-Skeleton is implemented in the `_cvConstructSkeleton()` and `_cvLee()` functions in [opencv/src/cvaux/cvlee.cpp](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/src/cvaux/cvlee.cpp?rev=27).

I haven't seen any official documentation about how to use this functionality in OpenCV. Since `cvlee.cpp` is in the `cvaux` folder, I think these may be experimental OpenCV functions.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your time. Seems that the function is already been there for quite some time. new version of opencv does not include it yet also. but anyway thanks.

Comment: That's true. If this was helpful, feel free to accept an answer.