# Junction point in image skeleton

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, point, junction

What is the meaning of a junction point in image skeleton ? I am using opencv and c++ to develop a code source to detect the main local junction point in the image .Many thanks in advace .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A junction point is usually the intersection of two lines.  See this image:

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByS6Z5WRz-h2U3NBWWZ6V3FqeUk/edit?pli=1

Skeleton refers (usually) to the skeletonization of an image.  this article is useful:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_skeleton.

So I think what they are asking you do is, to take the image find its skeleton then figure out which pixel contain the intersection of the lines of the skeleton.

[Skeletonization in opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12488894/skeletonization-in-opencv)

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer .Please , have you any idea how can I find the junction point if it is the intersection between two curve edge in the skeleton ?

Answer (score 0):

isn't it as simple as:

```
a junction has 2 or more neighbour pixels of the same color
```

?

Comment: Thank you for your answer . Please could you provide me with an example or algorithm ?I am currently working with binary image

Comment: Consider a matrix N=
[p9 p2 p3;
p8 p1 p4;
p7 p6 p5]
Array A= [p9 p8 p7 p6 p5 p4 p3 p2]
Array B=[p8 p7 p6 p5 p4 p3 p2 p9]                         S=sum(abs(A-B))
Condition on the pixel to be
- A junction point : (p1==1)&&(S>=6)///My problem is how to detect the main junction
- An free point : (p1==1)&&(S==2)

Comment: int same = (p9==p1); same += (p8==p1); same += (p7==p1); ....   bool junction = same >=2;