# Releated to android image processing

Tags: android

What is the meaning of a junction point in image skeleton ? I am using android to develop a source code to detect the junction point in the image. Is it necessary to use openCv sdk in android for image processing or to finding junction points?Many thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Junction point in image skeleton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16447975/junction-point-in-image-skeleton)

Comment: can you plz explain it what are possible duplicates?